# Authentication error when connect to Google Tasks API by HttpClient

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I am trying to connect to the Google Tasks by using HttpClient but always get "Unauthorised HttpResponseException".

Here is my code inside the "run" method of the AccountManagerCallback

```
 @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        // Get the result of the operation from the AccountManagerFuture.
        Bundle bundle;
        try {
            bundle = result.getResult();
            token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
            Log.i("#######", token); // token does have value

            String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists?key=" + your_api_key;
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            getRequest.addHeader("client_id", your_client_id);
            getRequest.addHeader("client_secret", your_client_secret);
            getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(getRequest, new BasicResponseHandler()); // exception raised here

            Log.i("###", responseBody); // cannot get the response here     

        } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

I am using Google APIs Level 10 emulator which does have access to the internet and I did add an google account into it.

Appreciate for any helps or suggestions to make my code work. Thanks.

Comment: getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + token); -- my hunch is that the problem is here. are you absolutely sure to prepend "OAuth " to the token?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I am pretty sure "OAuth " should be there.  I figured out that the invalid token is the problem. I just remove the account in the emulator and add it again, and that solved my problem. Thanks